# How to use a MembershipProvider in Winforms without defining an app.config?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

How can I use a `MembershipProvider` in a Winforms application without defining `ConnectionStrings`, `Membership` and `RoleManager` sections in app.config but creating instead all needed objects and configuration settings at runtime?

Comment: Are you implementing your own MemberShipProvider class by inheriting CustomMemberShipProvider class?

Comment: @Anuraj I am using SqlMemebershipProvider

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Initialize method of SqlMembershipProvider for providing the config values.

> Initializes the SQL Server membership
>   provider with the property values
>   specified in the ASP.NET application's
>   configuration file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.initialize.aspx

But it is also mentioned in the documentation, its not intended to be used directly from your code.